# At what time in the week is the Internet traffic low?

Tags: traffic

At what time in the week (at what hours) is the Internet traffic statistically low?

Comment: Impossible to answer generally. At least provide a country, preferably also the type of site.

Comment: @PerJohansson Why? There are just a few important backbones, and one could make a weighted average of their traffic.

Answer (score 1):

My guess will go on 3-5 am in the morning.

And if you are thinking for a server you have to know which country most of the visitors come from and use their time zone.

It's not something I have proofs of, but assume it's that way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when it's nighttime in North America, especially from Monday until Thursday (as Friday night falls on in the weekend). But that's just my guess.

Answer (score 0):

4am, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_rush_hour):

> a Google Analytics report dated 2017 indicates very strongly that daily web use peaks between 9am and midday, falling off steadily throughout the day with a modest levelling off between 7pm and 10pm, and then **collapses to a base at 4am.**

Unfortunately, nothing in that Wikipedia article (or the link it cites as its source for the "4am" figure) specify timezone.  I guess assume `America/New_York`?

Here's a graph from [the article Wikipedia cites](https://www.hallaminternet.com/google-analytics-hour-of-day-day-of-week-reports):
[image: a graph showing Internet usage levels at different times of day]